# Firebase. Authentication and hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I am creating a web page. I am using Firebase and Angular. I did it the authentication in the past installing the SDK with:

> npm install --save firebase

Then I used the *require* or *import*, and config code in a *firebase.js*:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...
  authDomain: ...
  projectId: ...
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const keep_session = firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION;
```

But now I have use hosting at same time. And [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-hosting-urls) tells it is same way using:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

With this in **body** block, looks it same than before.
The problem is when I use *ng serve,* with port 4200, I see in console it doesn't recognise the scripts.
When I do *firebase serve* yes, but it doesn't show my web. Only a example web page. With my firebase libraries yes, but no my content.

So my doubt is how I can make this.
Really with this scripts I can install SDK in my app? When I write code, it doesn't recognise.
Should I use the other way, installing dependencies?

Also I would know how when I write

> firebase serve

with the 5000 port, have the same result than when I use in the 4200

> ng serve

In my project, about firebase only I have *firebase.json* and *.firebaserc* files. Nothing about it in *package.json*.

Thank by the help.

---

**Edit:**
Doing *ng build* and then modifing *firebase.json*

```
"hosting": {
    ...
    "public": "dist/app_name",
    ...
}
```

I finally saw my web with

> firebase serve

So the question now is, How I develop if I don't have the module in my package.json? The IDE doesn't recognise when I make the imports

Comment: I see maybe they are 2 questions. One, I add libraries to app with scripts, and other how compile and show my app with _firebase serve_. But I think solving one I fix the other.

Answer (score 1):

Those specific script includes that you're using that being with two underscores only work when the web site is hosted with Firebase Hosting or its local emulator (`firebase serve`).  They won't work otherwise (including `ng serve`).

If you're using a bundler (which Angular does), you would not what to use those script includes at all.  When the app builds, the relevant code will come from the modules that were installed when you ran `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks Doug.
So, should  I always use the _npm install_ for this cases? 
I am thinking that if I can put complete app for work with local emulator, maybe this will work. But for now only it shows:
Welcome
_Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!_
Also I think if I make the _npm_, I will have them 2 times the libraries of firebase, no?

Comment: Do whatever you prefer or whatever meets your needs.  I have no opinion.  All I can tell you is why those scripts aren't working in your case.